# How to show margin on left, right and bottom of showModalBottomSheet?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

For the showModalBottomSheet i want to display margin around it. Mainly left and right. SO that it will look separated from the screen sides. How to achieve that. Also If i want to provide margin at the bottom, how to achieve that. Is there any other widget which provides the similar behavior as modalbottomsheet but with the margins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with flutter you can use any widget
Here is an example

```
_showModalBottomSheetCustom(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
         child: ...
      );
    }
  );
}
```

## EDIT

The margin is between the modal and the child, to "see" it, insert the transparent color on the modal

```
_showModalBottomSheetCustom(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
         color: Colors.white,
         margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
         child: ...
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that. The container is inside the modal. So the margin goes between the modal and container. Not between the modal and phone screen boundary.

Comment: @Braj I'm sorry, I didn't fully understand your problem, I changed the answer

Comment: Ahh.. I see what you did there. When will i become this smart on ui. Is there any book on such tips or any blog?

Comment: eh unfortunately I can't tell you, I only use the flutter documentation. But you can try to take a look at this too https://medium.com/flutter-community

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,It worked for me.

```
Get.bottomSheet(
    new Container(
    //height: 150,
    color: Colors.white,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Wrap(
    children: [
        ListTile(
        title: Text('title',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        ),
        Divider(),
        ListTile(
        title: Text('title',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        ),
        Divider(thickness: 9),
        ListTile(
        title: Text('title',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.horizontal()),
        ),
    ],
    ),
));
```

The result:

[image: Result]]

Comment: Thank You ,I will try to improve.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do is using constraints like here

```
 showModalBottomSheet(        
        context: context,
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40, // here increase or decrease in width
        ),
        builder: (context) {
          return BottomSheetContent();
        });
```